# javascript: слишком длительная загрузка данных с сервера

Tags: javascript, оптимизация, fetch, асинхронность

загружаю данные с сервера:

```
    // сформировать и передать запрос на сервер
    const t1: number = Date.now();

    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method:         'POST',
        headers:        {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body:           data)
    });

    const t2: number = Date.now();

    // получить ответ от сервера и преобразовать его в JSON
    const output: any = await response.json();

    const t3: number = Date.now();
```

даже если я пересылаю условно пустые данные и от сервера получаю условно пустые данные (т.е. объём данных очень небольшой), то между временные отметками `t2` и `t1` проходит около 2 секунд (!!!), при этом сервер находится в локальной сети в том же здании, а сам запрос на сервере выполняется где-то за 10-50 мсек.

подскажите в чем может быть дело и можно ли повысить скорость выполнения запросов? или это непреодолимый барьер на который никак нельзя повлиять?

Comment: В инструментах разработчика на вкладке сеть есть много разной полезной информации о запросе.

Comment: в консоли тоже показывает, что запрос идет 1,7 сек, Request/Response  DURATION
Request sent 
​
96 μs
Waiting for server response 
​
1.78 s
Content Download 
​
0.79 ms


Т.е. сервер все таки что-то не то делает?

Comment: А в инструментах с разбиением на этапы. Тебе ж надо понять что именно тормозит

Comment: Ну если браузер полторы секунды ждал ответа от сервера, то копать надо сервер и/или сеть

Comment: Может на сервере ресурсов нет и запрос в очереди ждёт…